# Approaches for multiclass classification with a reference level to extract variables of importance?

Tags: random-forest, machine-learning-model, multiclass-classification, feature-extraction, linear-models

I have a dataset with with multiple classes (< 20) which I want to classify in reference to  one of the classes.The final goal is to extract the variables of importance which are useful to distinguish each of the classes vs reference. If it helps to frame the question, an example would be to classify different cancer types vs a single healthy tissue and determine which features are important for the classification of each tumour.

My first naive approach would be to subset the dataset and compare individually each non-reference class to the reference using any number of appropriate methods, starting with generalised linear model and / or random forest, determine model performance and extract VIPs for each comparison. Basically a loop.

However this feels inelegant, so I am wondering which other approaches should be considered for problem.

Comment: If it matters for the answers, the implementation will probably be in `R` (`tidymodels`) but python suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: If you want to find which features were important in the prediction of your model you could look into SHAP values or LIME, which both seem to have packages for python and R.

Comment: Cheers @Oxbowerce. That part I think I got covered - thought those are good tips, the main question is which other models/approaches would be good starting points for a reference vs class  A, reference vs class  B, (...) classification problem.